# Running parallel projects in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I wrote a groovy script for running parallel projects in SoapUI and placed it in a test step in a project named 'Project1'. I am able to run the projects parallely but when i use a batch file for the purpose of scheduling the execution, it fails.  It says

`"Cannot get property 'projects' on null object"`

for the line defining 'project1'. Still it executes the first project as the groovy script is in the 'Project1'.

The groovy script for parallel execution of projects:

```
import   com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.DefaultPropertyExpansionContext

def project1=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.projects["Project1"]
def project2=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.projects["Project2"]

DefaultPropertyExpansionContext con1=new DefaultPropertyExpansionContext(project1) 
DefaultPropertyExpansionContext con2=new DefaultPropertyExpansionContext(project2) 
project1.run( con1,true)
project2.run( con2,true)
```

Comment: When you run the project as `batch` using `loadtestrunner.bat` you specify only one project... so `workspace` it's not available running the script in batch mode.  
Can you share your command?

Comment: "C:\SmartBear\SoapUI-Pro-5.1.2\bin\testrunner.bat -sServiceAPIs -j -f"D:\SoapUI Reports\S2S_APIs" -o -g -R"TestSuite Report" -EDefault -I D:\NAMI\OnlineBankTransfer.xml" is the command in the batch file.

Comment: Is there no way of doing this through a batch file?

Comment: I'm not an expert on `testrunner.bat` so I can't assure that it isn't possible, however looking on properties documentation for this command I don't see nothing related... see my answer. Hope it helps `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `SOAPUI` projects using `testrunner.bat` you've to note that you run the projects individually so you can't access to `testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace` property.

Looking at [`testrunner.bat` properties on documentation](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html) doesn't seems that there is no parameter that fits your requirements.

Maybe I'm wrong and there is something for this case (I'm not an expert using `testrunner.bat`), however a possible workaround to run both projects in parallel is to avoid call your `groovy testStep` an instead invoke `testrunner.bat` twice, specifying the correct project `xml` file for each one invocation.

Another possible workaround (which is basically the same) is to modify your `groovy` script to execute the both commands (instead of you call it from command line). So you execute using `testrunner.bat` a project with the follow `groovy testStep` script which execute the other projects. Try modifying your groovy script for something like:

```
def project1 = ["$SOAPUI_HOME/testrunner.bat","-sServiceAPIs","-j","-f",..].execute()
def project2 = ["$SOAPUI_HOME/testrunner.bat","-sServiceAPIs","-j","-f",..].execute()
```

Note that a String is needed for each param in your command and  `execute()` don't wait for command finish so your projects run in parallel.

If you want more info about `groovy` command execution take a look at [documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy).

Hope this helps,

Comment: But my intention is to run projects parallely. So, if i dont use my groovy script then is there any way to execute batch files for the projects parallely?

Comment: Running both project with command line directly, could be a workaround... they runs in parelel, maybe there is a minimum delay between each invocation but nothing important. Anyway I give you another possibility which is basically the same (running the both commands) but using `groovy testStep` if this feels you more comfortable `:)`

Comment: I have done as you said and it worked also, but is it going to affect in any way the license of SoapUI Pro?

Comment: @nishantnalin the license of SOAPUI PRO? Why? sorry, I don't really understand your question.

Comment: I am using SoapUI Pro(Licensed version), and i was thinking that since i am using two test runners at a time so will it lead to the cancellation of my license. One of my friends is in doubt and he thinks that it may lead to the deactivation of the license. So i wanted to make sure, if you have any knowledge regarding this, then please share.

Comment: @nishantnalin I don't think so you're running the two test runners from the same machine, however this is only my opinion and I don't really know... sorry `:(`. However if you're not using a PRO features inside this test maybe it's better to use a free version for this... another options is to ask a new question `:)` someone can give you a more exact answer. Sorry for that I can't give more help regarding this because I don't have any idea about licenses.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried it and it led to the deactivation of the license as it thinks that the license is being used by two machines ;)